# MVC Convention over Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm building a .NET MVC application. This is mobile web and i cannot use jQuery.
In my application every process is a 3 step action witch leads me to a 3 aspx per process.
My processes can be categorized so i'd like to code my controllers like: ProcessTypeAController, ProcessTypeBController.
My Views should be like: \ProcessTypeA\Process1\1.aspx, \Views\ProcessTypeA\Process1\2.aspx and \Views\ProcessTypeA\Process1\3.aspx.

By convention this not work because the Controllers dont have the same "location" than Views.

Please Help in this question!

Thank U ALL.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the location of a view:

```
return View("~/Views/ProcessTypeA/Process1/1.aspx");
```

As an alternative you could write a custom view engine in order to modify the default view location conventions. Scott Hanselman wrote an excellent [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) about how this could be achieved.